# Combining rows based on date in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the dataframe below and I would like to find the average global value for each date, and therefore having 1 row for each date. This is what i tried doing but didn't work:

```py
df_grouped = dfRead.groupby([dfRead['date']])['Global'].mean().reset_index()
```

Dataframe i currently have

```
      date  Global
0     1900   1.461
1     1900   3.098
2     1900   5.492
3     1900   8.223
4     1900  11.385
...    ...     ...
1363  2013  14.742
1364  2013  13.154
1365  2013  10.256
1366  2013   7.424
1367  2013   4.724
```

What I want the result to look like:

```
      date  Global
0     1900   2.461
1     1901   4.001
2     1902   5.620
...    ...     ...
113   2013   7.742
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! Just a slight change:

```
df_grouped = dfRead.groupby('date')['Global'].mean().reset_index()
```